# shared_ptr vs CComPtr

Tags: c++, com, shared-ptr

I'm somewhat used to the concept of refcounting through COM and I'm somewhat new to shared_ptr. There are several nice properties with CComPtr that I don't find in shared_ptr, and I'm wondering what are the pattern that prevent missuse of shared_ptr.

- The AddRef/Release pattern guarantees there is only one refcount per object (the refcount is stored on the object itself), so it's safe, when you have a random pointer to create a CComPtr around it. On the other hand, shared_ptr has a separate refcount pointer, so it's unsafe to create a new shared_ptr on an object (why does the standard provide a constructor that takes a T* on shared_ptr if it's so unsafe to do?). That seems such a big limitation that I don't understand how one can use shared_ptrs...
- A bit corner case: something that I've done in the past with AddRef/Release: I want a container of "weak references" to IFoos (for example a map from URL to IConnection or something). With weak_ptr, I can do that but my collection won't "clean itself up", I'll have expired pointers in it. With Release, I can implement my own weak pointer (a bit of work) that actually cleans up the collection. Is there an alternative with shared/weak_ptr?
- Intuitively, there is a performance penalty in doing two memory allocations to create an object (one for the refcount, one for the object) compared to the IUnknown world where you do only one. There is also a locality penalty when accessing the object (assuming that an AddRef is frequently followed by reading the content of the object, which seems likely). Has the cost of both approaches been compared?

Comment: You don't incur two allocations if you use `make_shared`. Otherwise, please post your actual use case, as it is hard to argue in thin air. `shared_ptr` is pretty good, but it's not the only solution for all situations.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Note that `make_shared` doesn't require that. All implementations will do it, but it's not strictly a requirement.

Comment: The big difference with CComPtr is that this class doesn't have to store the reference count.  It is kept in the object.  Doesn't have to worry about threading either, big deal to perf.

Answer (score 7):

> why does the standard provide a constructor that takes a T* on shared_ptr if it's so unsafe to do?

Because it's the only way to have `shared_ptr`s without being *intrusive*. You can use a `shared_ptr` on *anything*. I've even used them on objects from C interfaces, via the use of a deleter object. Things like a `cairo_t*` and so forth. That way, I never have to free anything ever again.

You can't do that with `CComPtr`; it only works for `IUnknown`-style objects.

Also, there is `std::make_shared`, which creates a `shared_ptr` directly from an object type and the argument to the constructor. So you never even see the pointer (and it usually allocates the object and its ref-count in one allocation instead of two).

The proper C++ idiom with `shared_ptr` is very simple: always use `make_shared` or `alloc_shared`. If you *can't* use them, then the proper idiom is to *only* use the direct naked pointer constructor in tandem with `new`: `shared_ptr<T> pVal{new T{...}};` (or the appropriate function that creates the pointer). Never use it on pointers that you don't know the origin of.

> Is there an alternative with shared/weak_ptr?

No, but there are tools to make one if you so desire. Besides the obvious method (run through your collection periodically and remove dead `weak_ptr`s), you can associate a deleter with the `shared_ptr` that will (in addition to deleting the pointer) call whatever cleanup function to remove those `weak_ptr`s.

> Intuitively, there is a performance penalty in doing two memory allocations to create an object

See `make_shared`, above.

> There is also a locality penalty when accessing the object (assuming that an AddRef is frequently followed by reading the content of the object, which seems likely).

You don't have to copy the `shared_ptr` to talk to its contents, nor do you have to bump the reference count to do so.

Now, let's talk about some of the things `CComPtr` *can't* do. It's intrusive. It can't be used with arbitrary allocators or deleters (obviously not as important when it's intrusive). It can't do pointer aliasing, where you have a `shared_ptr` to a member of an object, but the actual reference count is for the object it is a member of. That's a very useful thing to be able to do.

Oh yeah, it's *not cross-platform*. It's not bound to COM, `IUnknown`, and all of *that* overhead.

Comment: "always use make_shared or alloc_shared": why does the standard provide the constructor that takes a T* if I am to never use it (and always use make_shared)?
I understand that the perf penalty is removed by using make_shared, that's cool.
Do you find yourself creating classes that are both instanciated with make_shared and through other means (say unique_ptr)? How is intrusive limiting?
AddRef/Release can do aliasing (since you implement the APIs, you can redirect the call). The concept of intrusive refcounting is cross platform (I mean, the standard could have adopted a "CComPtr like" class)

Comment: @user1204233: Did you not read the very next sentence where I said, "If you *can't* use them..."? There are circumstances where it is impossible to use them. You should use them where possible, and where not possible use something else. As to the limits of intrusive refcounting, show me how to use that with a `cairo_t` or *any* pre-existing class without *modifying* the class. Having to modify code to use a smart point is a limitation. Not everyone owns every piece of code they use. You can use `shared_ptr` with `vector`, `string`, iostreams, any any future class anyone anywhere writes.

Comment: @user1204233: "I mean, the standard could have adopted a "CComPtr like" class" That's not the question you *asked*. You asked about `CComPtr` specifically, so I answered you about `CComPtr` specifically. If you revise your question to be more specifically about intrusive reference counting, then I'll revise my answer. And likely have it moved to Programmers.se.

Comment: Stay calm, I didn't mean to offend anyone... What are the circumstances when you can't use make_shared?
You can put an IString around a string that adds the refcount, you now have a new class that you can addref/release. You could even templatize that to have with_ref<string> which would be a class that exposes AddRef/Release. Come to think of it, that's exactly the same pattern... except there is a way to create a new shared_ptr around an existing string (which you shouldn't do) but there is no way to transform a string in a with_ref<string> (except downcasting, which you shouldn't do :))

Comment: @user1204233: "What are the circumstances when you can't use make_shared?" That's a new question, as is the concept of "IString" and such. Maybe you should ask that question; it sounds like a good question to ask. Stack Overflow isn't a forum; comment sections are not for follow-up questions. If an answer led you to new questions, use the Ask Question button to ask them.